# What happened to AppsFlyer partner ID?

Tags: appsflyer

Does anyone know what happened to AF PIDs? Before one ad network had one AF PID, now the same PID occurs in different ad networks and gives different performances.
Does anyone know how can it be explained?
https://support.appsflyer.com/hc/en-us/articles/207447163-Attribution-link-structure-and-parameters#pid
#AppsFlyer #adnetwork #adperformance

Tried to activate unique PID for unique ad campaign.